# How to cast value as JSON in MariaDB?

Tags: json, casting, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I want to extract a JSON with table name and columns inside each table.

Here is my SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECTAGG(table_name, columns)
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        JSON_OBJECTAGG(column_name, data_type) as columns
    FROM `COLUMNS`
    WHERE
        `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_db'
    GROUP BY table_name
) table_columns
```

The problem is in `JSON_OBJECTAGG(table_name, columns)`, columns became string. How to cast it as JSON?

Comment: The inner query has already aggregated on `table_name`, so I don't see what you are trying to achieve with the outer query. This is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=36a6665504db18a2bd7a149c101ffe23) I came up with (altering `TABLE_SCHEMA` criteria because of dbfiddle limitation). Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `JSON_EXTRACT(column_value_in_json, '$')`

```sql
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECTAGG(
        table_name,
        JSON_EXTRACT(
           columns,
           '$'
        )
    )
FROM (
    SELECT
        table_name,
        JSON_OBJECTAGG(column_name, data_type) as columns
    FROM `COLUMNS`
    WHERE
            `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'my_db'
    GROUP BY table_name
) table_columns
```

Comment: OMG I have been looking for this answer for days now!! The problem is that JSON in MariaDB is very different from MySQL's, so every possible solution you find may or may not work!. Thanks.